# How can I retrive coding sequences of mitochondrial genomes in R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I want to download coding sequences from nearly 400 mitogenomes. I have tried using getCDSSet() of biomartr R package. But it shows the following error.

```
getCDSSet( db       = "genbank", 
           organism = genbank_ID,
           reference = FALSE,
           path     = file.path("_/CDS"))
```

Error:
A summary file (which can be used as supplementary information file in publications) containig retrieval information for all species has been stored at 'C:/Users/DELL/CDS_summary.csv'.

Cleaning file names for more convenient downstream processing ...
Error: Some of the meta.retrieval() output files seem not to exist. Please provide valid file paths to meta.retrieval() output files.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
2: In stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
argument is not an atomic vector; coercing

For the argument 'organim', i used a vector of genbank accession ids: c("MK953813","AM889139",    "FJ752436","KF951091").

A help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're entering gene accession ids as organism, you need to find the taxonomy id for your organisms. for example, organism = "9606" (taxid of Homo sapiens) or search the organism name here for id 
[Accipiter trivirgatus](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?mode=Info&id=210844)

The path argument should be the location of a folder where your data shall be stored. leave the default value, it should create the folder in your working directory, or specify the full path to a folder.

```
getCDSSet(db = "genbank",
          organism = "210844",
          reference = FALSE,
          path = "myCDS")
```